# How do I add tab completion to the Python shell?

Tags: python, shell, interpreter

When starting a django application using `python manage.py shell`, I get an InteractiveConsole shell - I can use tab completion, etc.

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Apr 15 2008, 22:57:26) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
```

When just starting a python interpreter using `python`, it doesn't offer tab completion.

Can someone tell me what django is doing to give me an interactive console, or what I need to do to start an interactive console without a django app?

Comment: When you type in python, you get a >>> prompt, right?  That's the interactive shell.  What's your question?

Comment: It doesn't offer tab completion. That is the problem.

Comment: Please update your question to specify that.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

I may have found a way to do it.

Create a file .pythonrc

```
# ~/.pythonrc
# enable syntax completion
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print("Module readline not available.")
else:
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

then in your .bashrc file, add

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc
```

That seems to work.

Comment: this works for Jython where IPython and bpython are not currently available.

Comment: For some reason, the above worked for me in my old mac with "mountain lion" but not working for new mac with "el captan". I need to ``source ~/.bashrc`` everytime to make it work before starting python interpreter. Any tips?

Comment: @hmi Try unifying your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` as suggested at the bottom of this page: http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html It also provides information on the difference between them. It might not solve the issue, but it might help.

Comment: @hmi Try putting it in `/etc/bashrc`, instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Just for reference - I've probably come back to this answer more times than any other on StackOverflow, so thanks.

Answer (score 35):

I think django does something like https://docs.python.org/library/rlcompleter.html

If you want to have a really good interactive interpreter have a look at 
[IPython](https://ipython.org/).

Answer (score 27):

For the record, this is covered in the tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interactive.html

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged, please expand your answer

Answer (score 14):

I use [ptpython](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/ptpython/) - it is a wonderful tool autocomplete shell cmd.

Installing ptpython is very easy, use pip tool

```
pip install ptpython
```

**and for django shell, you should import the django env, like this**

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testweb.settings")
```

Trust me, this is the best way for you!!!

Answer (score 8):

Fix for Windows 10 shell:

```sh
pip install pyreadline3  # previously, pyreadline but that package was abandoned
pip install ipython
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python3 this feature is enabled by default. My system didn't have the module `readline` installed. I am on Manjaro. I didn't face this tab completion issue on other linux distributions (elementary, ubuntu, mint).

After `pip` installing the module, while importing, it was throwing the following error-

`ImportError: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

To solve this, I ran-

`cd /usr/lib
ln -s libncursesw.so libncursesw.so.5`

This resolved the import error. And, it also brought the tab completion in the python repl without any creation/changes of `.pythonrc` and `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's built in to 3.6.

```
fernanr@gnuruwi ~ $ python3.6
Python 3.6.3 (default, Apr 10 2019, 14:37:36)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.
Display all 318 possibilities? (y or n)
os.CLD_CONTINUED             os.O_RDONLY                  os.ST_NOEXEC                 os.environ                   os.getpid(                   os.readlink(                 os.spawnvpe(
os.CLD_DUMPED                os.O_RDWR                    os.ST_NOSUID                 os.environb                  os.getppid(                  os.readv(                    os.st
```

Comment: Hi what key did you press to get "Display all 318 possibilities? (y or n)". I tried 'tab' key it doesn't give me your auto-complete hint. I must be missing something simple

Comment: yes, tell how did it get autocomplete, which key or any setup needed, eager to know!

Answer (score -2):

For older versions (2.x) above script works like charm :)

```sh
fernanr@crsatx4 ~ $ cat .bashrc | grep -i python
#Tab completion for python shell
export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc
fernanr@crsatx4 ~ $ . ~/.bashrc
fernanr@crsatx4 ~ $ echo $?
0
fernanr@crsatx4 ~ $ python2
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.
Display all 249 possibilities? (y or n)
os.EX_CANTCREAT             os.O_WRONLY
```

Comment: Your reply seems to be missing the content of "~/.pythonrc"

Comment: @MadMike I suspect it was intended to be shown below [ashchristopher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246779/294313) ... not sure why it's an answer, though.