# Where to find reference for PyGObject

Tags: documentation, pygobject

I'm working on a Python based source code editor. I've created a clean layout with a `Gtk.Notebook`. Creating a main layout was easy with Glade, but right after I imported `gi.repository`, everything got hard. It's very hard to find documentation. From `pydoc` I can 't get anything, only method signatures, which are usually *args, **kwargs. I often need to check what a method returns or takes in, and I haven't really started signals and other stuff yet.

Is there a complete/almost-complete documentation, especially for GtkSource? GtkSource is especially undocumented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably read my answer to a similar SO question: [PyGObject GTK+ 3 Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586396/pygobject-gtk-3-documentation/11589779#11589779). In short, you should refer to the [GtkSourceView API Reference](http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/) for C. Don't worry, it's not hard. When you see "GtkSourceView" in the C docs you know it's "GtkSource.View" in Python. When you see "gtk_source_view_new" in C docs you know it's the constructor in Python "GtkSouce.View()". You can set *any* GTK+ property in the constructor and there is usually get_foo/set_foo style methods for each property.

Therefore, you can do things like:

```
view = GtkSouce.View(indent_width=4, show_line_numbers=True)
view.get_buffer().set_text("Hello World!")
```

Remember, GTK+ widgets are objects so you need to pay attention to the hierarchy to find all the methods and properties for a widget.

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting more comfortable with this as I'm learning it.