# How to set the alignment, or how to find PyGObject documentation

Tags: python-2.7, gtk3, pygobject, pango

I am trying to right-align some text content in a CellRenderer. Through several searches I found two approaches, but these do not work. With bold-setting, you need to enable this feature first, so I am guessing I also need to enable alignment setting, but have not found how to do this. This runs without exception:

```
r = Gtk.CellRendererText()
r.props.width_chars = 10
r.set_property('alignment', Pango.Alignment.RIGHT) # no effect
r.props.alignment = Pango.Alignment.RIGHT # no effect
r.props.weight_set = True # not really needed
r.props.weight = Pango.Weight.BOLD # works, output is bold
```

This is what I guessed from the bold example but does NOT work:

```
 r.props.alignment_set = True
```

The error is:  'gi._gobject.GProps' object has no attribute 'alignment_set'

Looking at these references I do not find something on GProps:

- [GObject Ref Manual](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GObject-2.0/classes/)
- [Gtk3 Ref Manual](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0)

This resource does say something about alignment, but it is unclear to me how to convert this C code to Python/GObject:

- [Gnome Gtk3 Manual for C](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRenderer.html#gtk-cell-renderer-set-alignment)

My question is how to fix this problem, where is the ref manual for this PyGObject error message, or how should I code the right-alignment?

---

Update:
I am currently looking at [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586396/pygobject-gtk-3-documentation) for clues.

As for the comment of TingPing, I looked at [the set_alignment() method](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRenderer.html#gtk-cell-renderer-set-alignment),and tried these:

```
r.set_alignment(Pango.Alignment.RIGHT) # error: set_alignment() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
r.set_alignment(200, 0) # no error, no effect
```

besides this method seems intended to create some pixels padding at the left, which is not what I need: align text to the right of the cell space.

---

Update:

Perhaps the above code is good, but perhaps the CellRenderer() has no intrinsic width, no excess space to put to the left of the content. I thought of this because of thinking of simply left-padding my numberic cell content with spaces. Then I need to decide on the maximum field length. Perhaps the CellRenderer does not 'know' about a default field length. I added a settinge to `.props.width_chars`, but this did unfortunately not cause any rignt-alignment.

Comment: You never need to touch the `*_set` properties. Otherwise your usage seems fine, the `set_alignment()` method does exist as its inherited from its parent so that is worth a shot.

Comment: @TingPing I tried your suggestion, see the update on my question. Thanks for your comments. I am getting the feeling that my posted code should work but that something else in my app is going wrong...  I wished I found an example of PyGObject and align-right ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through [this C example](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=2123) I tried this to right-align:

```
r.props.xalign = 1.0
```

and it works! The `xalign` is the fraction of free space 0..1.0 to put to the left of the text. The value 0.5 will center the text.

Comment: That actually helped me, in ruby-gtk too. xalign works there too. I was trying set_alignment() but this does something different.