# pycharm python console autocompletion

Tags: autocomplete, ipython, pycharm

if I start ipython in a terminal, when I type 'im' and press TAB, the terminal will auto-complete it with 'import', but when I click python console button in the bottom of pycharm IDE, when the ipython environment shows, type 'im', press TAB, it will not give autocompletion.

In PyCharm, it use pydevconsole.py to create the ipython environment, but I do not know how to change it to enable the autocompletion.

Comment: [autocompletion with python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246779/6521116)

Answer (score 5):

You can use Ctrl+Space for auto completion.
See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/using-consoles.html).

Answer (score 1):

ctrl+space confuse with input language switching of Windows. need change setting of Keymap

File -> Setting -> Keymap ->　Main menu -> Code -> Complete -> Basic