# how to use python like linux command line and visual studio auto fill

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Frankly, it's easy to forget the name of some property and sometimes it is difficult to enter the property name accurately.

How do I do the following thing using python from ubuntu terminal
after I enter Python Interpreter

```
python2
.... enter keras learning model
model = Sequential()
model.a tab tab i want sth to come out here
```

(1) use tab for autofill (similar to ubuntu terminal)

(2) after typing a letter show possible/recent selected property and variable

(3) show method and property of a variable without typing a letter

and many other helpful functions that can accelerate the coding

Comment: Have you tried just opening a python interpreter on the terminal? It usually does that, without having to configure anything.

Comment: I can run python2 or python3 Python Interpreter. Its inside how to make the life easier

Comment: It may not be what you want, but have you tried iPython?

Comment: tried before, cant get work with imported 3rd party module like pytorch, opencv. U get it working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246725/how-do-i-add-tab-completion-to-the-python-shell Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

As Julio P.C. point out

native python interpreter will not work. But iPython with a few more [actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246725/how-do-i-add-tab-completion-to-the-python-shell) will do the job