Tab syntax auto-complete doesn't work in the python shell installed by pyenv
I'm using pyenv and installed python 3.10.4 on ubuntu 20.04. So current python version list is as follows.
$ pyenv versions      
* system (set by /home/seongwoo/.pyenv/version)
  3.10.4

With system python (3.8.10), the auto-complete feature in the python interpreter works well like below.
import numpy
>>> numpy.
Display all 562 possibilities? (y or n)

But, when I switched to python 3.10.4 and do the same thing, pressing the tab just results in </t>.
Is there anybody who suffers from the same thing?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/246779 doesn't work for me. And, installed python 3.10.4 doesn't have readline. When I installed readline manually, it installed but crashed in the interpreter.
